# Format MySQL String value on select statement

Tags: java, mysql

I want to obtain sales(money) in a format of currency eg. 45,000.00

The record is existing as a varchar in the sales table.

i have tried the following but it seems not to work.

Help in solving the problem or suggest a better way of doing it.

```
Select format(sales,2) from sales_tbl where salesId=123;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Formatting numbers is the job of the presentation layer, not the job of a SQL query. 2. Why are you storing numbers in a varchar?

Comment: Not sure why you've tagged this Java.  Are you selecting this in a Java program?  What type of variable are you selecting it into?  How are you displaying it?

Comment: Java is the programming language under use in the system

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll want to use the SQL CAST keyword to cast from one datatype to another

```
SELECT CAST(SALES AS NUMERIC(p,2)) FROM SALES_TBL WHERE SALESID=123;
```

Make sure to put in an appropriate precision value in p.